# What is the proper way to normalize features with tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a data set, with features I would like to scale, with tensorflow.  The problem is that I don't understand what the mechanism is to apply a transformation on the input set and then, later, to a random input vector ( for a single prediction ).

What is a best practice pattern for normalizing a data set so that the mean and std can be preserved for later use?  In other words, when training a model, how can the defined pre-processing methods be applied at both training and testing time efficiently?

Edit: I think it might go something like this

```
init_dataset = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

init_dataset_normalized = normalize(init_data_set)

fit = model( init_dataset_normalized )

pred = fit.predict( normalize( random_input ))
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: You should add more details to your question. Ideally, you would provide a sample input-output pair along withyour code. Provided, you don't know, how to write this in temsorflow, you can use numpy or even pseudocode for illustration.

Comment: @EliKorvigo well what do you suggest if there is no sample.  Just an abstract idea?  The numbers are not important: just the pattern.

Comment: "_so that the mean and std can be preserved for later use_" – this part remains unclear.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for something like this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization

Comment: @EliKorvigo No. Batch Normalization is something different than feature scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have grayscale images, I use the following:

```
def scale(X):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        x.append(X[i].astype('float32'))
        x[i] /= 255.0
    return x
```

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, but I feel like tensorflow would have something like [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/data_preprocessing/).  I looking for and example,I guess

Comment: @grldsndrs, I don't know about that. I usually do my own normalization.